# Unable to use GPU Ubuntu 20.04 CUDA 10.2

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, tensorflow

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
>>> 
>>> # Create some tensors
>>> a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
2020-06-02 15:21:45.190704: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-06-02 15:21:45.239786: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-06-02 15:21:45.240144: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:2d:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.665GHz coreCount: 34 deviceMemorySize: 7.79GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2020-06-02 15:21:45.240252: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64::/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
2020-06-02 15:21:45.241228: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-06-02 15:21:45.242323: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-06-02 15:21:45.242467: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-06-02 15:21:45.243467: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-06-02 15:21:45.244029: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-06-02 15:21:45.246146: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-06-02 15:21:45.246159: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1598] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2020-06-02 15:21:45.246436: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-06-02 15:21:45.271855: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:102] CPU Frequency: 3799960000 Hz
2020-06-02 15:21:45.272326: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7f7008000b60 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-06-02 15:21:45.272349: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-06-02 15:21:45.274045: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-06-02 15:21:45.274060: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      
>>> b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
>>> c = tf.matmul(a, b)
```

The drivers and cuda-toolkit are installed fine.

It is skipping GPU devices while all the headers are loaded successfully.
It usually logs the one dependencies failed to load and then exits.

Guidance will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind managed to fix this, I was checking for errors in the middle or bottom while it appeared on the very first dsoloader line `sudo apt-get install cuda-cudart-10-1` was all I needed lol